# OpenNTF domino api not available for selection in designer

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Domino API is not available to be checked in the xpage properties of my databases

I am trying to use domino api to help with some of the recycling problems that we've had with xpages.  I've spent days watching the various videos that have been made over the years.  I have tried to get this working in both my work environment (9.0.1) and my home dev server (10).  In both cases the result is the same - I have installed the extension library and domino api on the server via updatesite and it seems to be fine there.  In my designer I can see that both extension library and domino api are installed (by looking in Application Management) but only extension library is available in the databases.

Need to be able to select the org.opentf library in the datbases.

Comment: Have you checked the Page Generation Properties for the database design? 
 From Domino Designer, look in Application Configuration, Xsp Properties, Page Generation tab.  Make sure to check com.ibm.extlib.library in Xpage libraries.  Do you see the extlib libraries there?

Comment: Please confirm versions installed. Various plugins avalable with DDE have changed at different versions of DDE, which means the correct ODA version needs to be installed.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers That's part of my confusion - what exactly am I comparing?  There are various versions available for download - they are matched up to the server fix pack.  If I have a 9 client should I get the fix pack for fp10?

Comment: In the osgi console I issued a diag statement and this is what is returned.  This is for a 9 client, if that helps.

/Data/workspace ........ org.openntf.domino_4.2.0.201709291450.jar [1416]
No unresolved constraints

Comment: We've tried to clarify in the release page. 4.2.x is for 9.0.1 FP9. Since 10 we've moved to updated version numbering, although Tycho doesn't make it straightforward. So 10.0.0 covers V10. The version in Notes needs to match the Notes version, not the Domino version. It's referenced for compiling only, not pulled into the design. So on the server, the version needs to match the Domino server version. So you may have different versions if DDE and the server are different. That's to do with how OSGi works.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers  Thanks so much Paul - it was in fact a version issue.  We hadn't installed client fix packs in ages.

I am hoping that you can answer one more question.   Over the years we've tried to make our code as lean as possible by not declaring objects unless we absolutely have to (e.g. to get a handle to a doc we would say db.getview.getDocument in a single statement so as to not needlessly declare view and risk having it not recycled correctly under the covers).  Should turning on godmode help with this?

Comment: Posted that as an answer now. Since 9.0.1 you have over 20,000 handles to individual Domino objects available per HTTP request (loading a page, partial refresh etc). Each view is a single handle. So unless you're opening up lots, there's no reason to worry about the number of handles, outside a loop. And db.getView().getDocument() still gets a handle anyway, so you're not saving anything. In fact it's now harder to recycle. Session gets recycled at the end of the request, and all descendants with it. There's no way to *not* recycle them. So they'll get recycled correctly anyway.

Comment: godmode will help to some extent, because `session` will then be an ODA Session. There are some edge cases where objects can be recycled over-aggressively, the cause hasn't been fully identified. If encountered, that can be prevented by using `session.setFixEnable(Fixes.PEDANTIC_GC_TRACKING, true);`

Answer (score 0):

We've tried to clarify in the release page. 4.2.x is for 9.0.1 FP9. Since 10 we've moved to updated version numbering, although Tycho doesn't make it straightforward. So 10.0.0 covers V10. The version in Notes needs to match the Notes version, not the Domino version. It's referenced for compiling only, not pulled into the design. So on the server, the version needs to match the Domino server version. So you may have different versions if DDE and the server are different. That's to do with how OSGi works.